# Rails - Incorrect Assets Loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

Occasionally I'll click a link in my application, and the *.css and *.js files that are loaded are referring to the wrong controller.  If I refresh the page, this is immediately fixed, but I do not want to tell my users that the occasional page refresh may be required.

This is where the content is loaded in my application layout:

```
= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller]
= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
= javascript_include_tag params[:controller]
```

And where the assets are loaded in my assets.rb initilizer

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'flash')

%w( comments contact_types ensembles favorite_instruments fields gds gigs instuments
rank_members recruit_statuses scores seasons section_notes sections static students
announcements ).each do |controller|
    Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ["#{controller}.js", "#{controller}.css"]
end
```

It's strange to me that sometimes it work work and other times, it would not.  I assume that I have a gem issue with some of the page loading stuff.  I am using `turbolinks`, `spring`, and `quiet_assets`.  I don't think any of the other gems touch assets.

Comment: Turn off turbo-links.

Comment: If possible turn off the turbo-links.

Answer (score 2):

TurboLinks intercepts requests and fetches only the body of the document, "seamlessly" substituting it into the DOM. It doesn't touch `<head>`, so your JavaScript includes are not changing until you fully reload the page and fetch a new document with the appropriate `<head>`.

TurboLinks (and Rails) assume you're going to have a single bundle of JavaScript, not many small conditionally included JavaScripts. You're going to have to either go the Rails-way, and stop using many small manifests, or turn off TurboLinks.

Comment: Some of the javascript is pretty heavy and very page-specific.  Hence the reason that I decided to break it all up. Your anser makes sense, is there a way to get some of the turbo-links benefits without combining all of the javascript?

Comment: Also, removing that fixed it.  I'll accept your answer once the time limit is up.